# Sorting a csv file alphabetically on Python

Tags: python, file, sorting, python-3.x, csv

I have done a math quiz as practice. Part of Task 3 is to organise a CSV file containing names and scores into alphabetical order. I have done some code, but I would like to know how to make it work like I expect it to. I'm not really sure what I have done, so please can you keep explanations simple.

```
data = input('How would you like the data? a for alphabetically, b for highest score  to lowest and c for average score highest to lowest. press q to exit: ')
if 'a':
    score_file = open('scorefile.csv')
    for x in sorted (score_file, key=str.lower):
        print (x)
```

This is what it looks like when it is run:
[image: code running]

Comment: Does your code work? `score_file` is not a list you can sort, you will have to read the lines first.

Comment: @DisplayName how could I change it to make it better?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader
A csv reader that can probably be of help

Comment: @jDO I added a picture of the running code above

Comment: @DisplayName I added a picture of the running code above

Comment: @SSchneid okay I will

Comment: @ClareJordan Your current code doesn't work as you expect. This is not about optimization. For instance, `if 'a':` will always be true; you're not checking whether the user actually entered an "a".

Comment: Hi @ClareJordan, you'd better use `anaconda` or `spyder` as a coding interface. It is much better to use these, in python, for windows

Comment: @AndyK okay thanks - can i use it on mac though because only use python on windows at school

Comment: @ClareJordan yes, you can

Comment: @AndyK okay thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what's going on here?

```
>>> if "a":
...     print ("True!")
... else:
...     print("False!")
... 
True!
>>> 
>>> if "aadasgabherbasdvc23d3wv":
...     print ("True!")
... else:
...     print("False!")
... 
True!
>>> 
>>> if "":
...     print ("True!")
... else:
...     print("False!")
... 
False!
>>> 
>>> if None:
...     print ("True!")
... else:
...     print("False!")
... 
False!
>>>
```

Any non-empty string will evaluate to `True`. Empty strings and the keyword `None` evaluate to `False` (there are probably more examples). 
This means that no matter what you enter, the code nested under `if 'a'` will be executed. If/when you write the code for user inputs "b" and "c", you'll see this.

If you want to compare user input to the string `'a'`, you'd do:

```
data = input('How would you like the data? a for alphabetically, b for highest score  to lowest and c for average score highest to lowest. press q to exit: ')
if data == 'a':
    # do something
```

Regarding the rest of the code... Python has a `csv` module. You can easily split a csv file manually since it should be comma-delimited but the `csv` module handles it in a slightly more sophisticated way (I'm not sure but I think it understands values with commas in them, for instance).

When you use `open()`, don't forget to call `close()` afterwards. You can avoid this `open/close` business altogether by using `with` (which is called a context manager btw.). You can then do

```
import csv

with open('scorefile.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    rows = csv.reader(csv_file)
```

or

```
with open('scorefile.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
       ...
```

or whatever you want to do with the file. The key point is that using `with` takes care of closing the file automatically once you're done reading the data. That way, you don't have to remember to call `close()`.

Comment: thankyou so much this has been such a great help!! 